# get and display multiple checkbox values from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

i having two check boxes when i am selecting both check boxes i want to show the value related to both from database ,but now i able to print only one id of check boxes i want to show both data can anyone help hoe to show both a value ,Below is my code:

html

```
 <input type="submit" name="Update" src="/image/exporttt.png" style="margin:0px;cursor:pointer">

<tbody>
<?php

$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];

if($clientid!=""){

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientnetworkpricehistory");


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo ' 
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" style="width:140px" class=" clientid '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["clientid"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_country" style="width:160px" class=" country '.$rows['net_id'].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>       
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_networkname" style="width:156px" class="networkname '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mccmnc" style="width:250px" class=" mcc'.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td> 
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mccmnc" style="width:250px" class=" mnc '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>         
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_oldprice" style="width:320px" class=" oldprice '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["pricefrom"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_newprice" style="width:129px" class=" newprice '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["priceto"].'</td> 
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_oldroute" style="width:143px" class="oldsupplierroute '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["routefrom"].'</td>    
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_newroute" style="width:143px" class=" newsupplierroute '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["routeto"].'</td>     
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_comments" style="width:143px" class=" comments '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.$rows["status"].'</td>      
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_from" style="width:143px" class=" fromdate '.$rows["net_id"].'">'.date('d.m.Y H:i', $rows["datetime"]).'</td>         

        <td style="width:65px" class=" '.$rows["net_id"].'"><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value=" '.$rows["net_id"].'"/></td>

        </tr>';
}
}
?>

</tbody>
```

jssearch.php

```
<?php
 //connecting to db     
$variable=$_POST['chk1'];
foreach ($variable as $variablename)
{
$sql_select="SELECT * from clientnetworkpricehistory where net_id=$variablename";
$queryRes = mysql_query($sql_select);
print"$sql_select";
}
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>country</th>
<th>networkname </th>
<th>mcc</th>
<th>mnc</th> 
        <th>datetime </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryRes))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['networkname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mcc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mnc'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['datetime'] . "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

my out put was(i am checked two checkboxes and i am trying to print two check boxes id it only showing one can any one help me how to do that)

```
56
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `name="chk1[]"` in your HTML so the checkboxes will be posted as an array.

Besides that:

1. The mysql_* functions are deprecated, consider using mysqli_* or PDO
2. You are vulnarable to SQL-injection on your `where net_id=$variablename"`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Peter but you also might wanna fix this little typo:

```
'.$rows['net_id'].'">'.$rows["country"].'
```

That's line 2 of that large `echo` you have with all the `<td>`s.  The `$rows['net_id']` should be double quotes.

But you knew that...:)